# 3rd Libraries: fatal error: Something.h: File does not exist

Tags: arduino-ide, library

> I created this question because I find many questions with similar problems, 
>   so I wanted to provide a reference/ more generic question for these type of problems.

For my projects I have installed 3rd party libraries by cloning from the library's git repository into the folder that `preferences.txt`'s `sketchbook.path` value exists into a folder named `libraries`. In other words if the `sketchbook.path` has the value `/home/myuser/sketchbook` I clone the repositories into the folder `/home/myuser/sketchbook/libraries`.

Then on the folder `/home/myuser/sketchbook/myexample` I store my code `myexample.ino` that needs a library with header files `Something.h`.

While I click on Arduino IDE the verify button I get the error:

```
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -Wall -fno-exceptions 
    -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -MMD 
    -DUSB_VID=null -DUSB_PID=null -DARDUINO=105 -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__         
    -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino 
    -I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard 
    -I/usr/share/arduino/libraries/SPI 
    /tmp/build6596169359663087897.tmp/LoRaSerialGateway.cpp -o 
    /tmp/build6596169359663087897.tmp/LoRaSerialGateway.cpp.o 
LoRaSerialGateway.ino:15:18: fatal error: Something.h: 
compilation terminated.
```

So my guess is that I cannot make avr-gcc to compile using the 3rd party library. Do you know how to pass into avr-gcc the correct paths for the appropriate libraries?

Comment: The Arduino IDE will handle it, provided the libraries are actually installed via the IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a working library system already, i.e., there are some libraries in `.../libraries` now and they compile properly or at least the compiler are successfully finds them; and you want to add another library, say "CrashAndBurn.h" and "CrashAndBurn.cpp", you need to put those two files into a folder named `.../libraries/CrashAndBurn/`. Then in your sketch, you add an include directive `#include <CrashAndBurn.h>`.

An alternative is to put the .h and .cpp files somewhere else, such as a folder under your project folder, and modify the include directive to point to them, as `#include "libs/CrashAndBurn.h"`, where the libs folder is within the sketch folder. Or you could put them in any folder, anywhere, and write an absolute path to them: `/home/some/place/else/CrashAndBurn.h`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you should modify a bit the library's file stricture in case of [this](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/arduino-LoRa) library in order to make it avaialble I moved the code in folder `./src` **outside** to the **project's** root folder.

Also an another problem is that you may use older version of the ide. Especially this can happen in GNU/Linux if you install the arduino ide from the distribution's repositories.

Comment: just rename the folder from zip to LoRa in libraries. no need to move files

Comment: I used the git method.

Comment: I create file system link from git folder to libraries folder, with the correct library name